# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'reactiveProp' of 'vue_chartjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.mixins' as it is undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-chartjs

I tried to check example from vue-chartjs.
But every time appears error:
[image]
Why it could be?This is an example from manual.
I installed by npm i vue-chartjs chart.js.
Tried clear package-lock.json, and repeatedly install this library.
But nothing chages.

Example.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="small">
      <line-chart :chart-data="datacollection"></line-chart>
      <button @click="fillData()">Randomize</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import LineChart from '@/LineChart.js'
export default {
  components: {
    LineChart
  },
  data () {
    return {
      datacollection: null
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.fillData()
  },
  methods: {
    fillData () {
      this.datacollection = {
        labels: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: '#f87979',
            data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
          }, {
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: '#f87979',
            data: [this.getRandomInt(), this.getRandomInt()]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    getRandomInt () {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 5 + 1)) + 5
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  .small {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin:  150px auto;
  }
</style>
```

Line.js

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
const { reactiveProp } = mixins


export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ['options'],
  mounted () {
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
  }
}
```

Comment: "I tried to check example from vue-chartjs" - which one?  vue-chartjs has no documented mixins import. If things that you expect to exist in a lib cannot be found, it's likely that package version is wrong

Comment: there the same example. But it's work. When I try to repeat this code in my workspace appears error: https://codesandbox.io/s/3dzt9?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: As said above, you need to look closely at package versions. The demo uses vue-chartjs 3, while the latest is 4

Comment: I downgraded version vue-chartjs from 4 to 3. And now have other error. Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: chart_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default is not a constructor"   [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keoWr.png

Comment: The error says which dep causes the error, it's chart_js. Just check all relevant package versions between this demo and your project.

Comment: I get it. I forget to change chart js package from 3 to 2